# To change the state of button highlighted from normal and keeping it hold

Tags: iphone

I am creating an iphone app where I have used 25 buttons and each button has been shown a background image in its normal mode.I have also set another image on the highlighted mode of the button.

Initially button will be shown in its normal mode 
now I want that when a button is pressed then button should change to its highlighted state so as the other image will be displayed there.
I have done so by doing:

`button.highlighted = YES;`

Its working but its sets the highlighted image for a fraction and then again normal state of the button come back. I use the following code to create the buttons.

```
for (int i=0; i<25; i++) {

    if (i > 0) { 

        if (i%5 == 0) {

            xaxis = 28;
            yaxis = yaxis+42;
        }
    } 

    iconButton[i] = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
    iconButton[i].frame = CGRectMake(xaxis, yaxis, 50, 40); 
    [iconButton[i] setBackgroundImage:[iconArray objectAtIndex:random] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
    [iconButton[i] setBackgroundImage:[tapedIconArray objectAtIndex:random] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [iconButton[i] addTarget:self action:@selector(changeImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
    [self.view addSubview:iconButton[i]]; 
    xaxis = xaxis+53; 
}
```

How can i hold the state of the button, I even tried with timer but app get crashed then.
Please help me

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the code how you are creating the button and assigning images to it?

Comment: Please put the code in your question It would be easier to find the solution/error

Comment: for(int i=0; i<25; i++)
 {if(i>0){if(i%5==0){xaxis=28;yaxis=yaxis+42;}}
 iconButton[i]=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 iconButton[i].frame=CGRectMake(xaxis, yaxis, 50, 40);
 [iconButton[i] setBackgroundImage:[iconArray objectAtIndex:random] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; [iconButton[i] setBackgroundImage:[tapedIconArray objectAtIndex:random] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];[iconButton[i] addTarget:self action:@selector(changeImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [self.view addSubview:iconButton[i]];
  xaxis=xaxis+53;
 }

Comment: Instead of `setBackgroundImage:`, did you try `setImage:`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of this but try it by setting image for button's UIControlStateSelected
i.e.

```
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: you're welcome... It is also good practice to accept answer of your question... judging from your points... you should go through faq...